# smbus write_word_data command

Tags: python

I am trying to use the smbus write_word_data command which takes three arguments addr, cmd, value - all of the documentation that I can find tells me that I need to specify cmd, but gives no clue as to what it is

Comment: Without having looked at the docs, and not being a python user, I'll still bet that `cmd` refers to the word size (2 bytes) of data you want to send.  This is because most often they do represent a command for the device -- e.g., to fetch a sensor reading, you might write 0xff (that's a word size value in hex) to a specific address, then do a read.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet for the device you are addressing will indicate if a particular SMBus command has any meaning for that device.  Some do, some don't.

The following information will be transmitted on the I2C bus for an SMBus write word data command.

`S Addr Wr [A] reg [A] word LSB [A] word MSB [A] P`

Where

S is the start condition

P is the stop condition

Addr is the device's 7 bit I2C address

Wr is a bit indicating this is an I2C write

reg (or cmd as used in your documentation) is the device register to write

[A] is the device acknowledging the byte

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of an example?

Comment: What sort of example?  Unless the command is appropriate to the I2C device you are using it's a useless command.  But see http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#i2c_write_word_data

Answer (score 0):

Not all devices need a `cmd` byte. If yours does not specify one, just use the first 'data' byte in its place and the remainder data in the data array, if necessary use an empty data array.

Note that SMBUS is not the same as I2C. SMBUS is built on top of I2C. Electrically they're pretty compatible but SMBUS adds some features that i2c doesn't have ('Command' being one of those).

If you find that it is an i2c device I'd suggest using the `i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data` and `i2c_smbus_write_i2c_block_data` which will be a little more straightforward.

The python smbus implements all of the functions described here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol

I think it does so pretty faithfully, so you can follow the i2c_* functions I specified above from the descriptions there.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that SMBus is not a superset of I2C.  I2C has just a read and write command, which can do everything SMBus commands can do and more.  Neither is I2C a superset of SMBus as SMBus has timeouts etc.

Comment: I thought the declaration 'smbus is built on top of i2c' makes that distinction. Here is a good article comparing the two: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa132/sloa132.pdf

Comment: "Built on top of" suggests that SMBus is a superset which it is certainly not.

Comment: From the SMBUS specification 3.0 "It is based on the principles of operation of the I2C bus." I think that's consistent with my characterization - pedantry be damned :)